# return results from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, matlab

I'm trying to call a stored procedured in microsoft sql server from matlab.

The stored procedure requires one input and returns one row with 10 columns where all columns are numeric.

I've been trying to follow the [matlab page](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/runstoredprocedure.html) but no joy. The error message I get is

```
 Error using database/runstoredprocedure (line 81)
Java exception occurred:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure or function usp_cap_wgt_factors has too many arguments specified.
```

**Matlab code**

```
inputarg = {'2016-03-11'};
outputtype = {java.sql.Types.NUMERIC};
results = runstoredprocedure(QES_DB,'usp_cap_wgt_factors', inputarg, outputtype);
```

**How I call my stored procedure in sql**

```
exec usp_cap_wgt_factors '2016-03-11'
```

**Update**

If I try the line below I get the following error message "Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object."

```
 inputarg = char(datestr('2016-03-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

**sql procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_cap_wgt_factors
@factDate as date   
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
;with totVal as
(
    select sedolchk,  mv_usd / (select sum(mv_usd) from D_FACTORS where pricedatew = @factDate) wgt
    from D_FACTORS where pricedatew = @factDate

), factors as
(
    select sedolchk, ubeta180w, ratebeta180w, yxdbeta180w, crbbeta180w, idiovol, lnr05204w, lnr18053w, mv_usd, bp from D_FACTORS 
    where pricedatew = @factDate
)
select sum(ubeta180w * wgt) ubeta180w, sum(ratebeta180w * wgt) ratebeta180w, sum(yxdbeta180w * wgt) yxdbeta180w,
sum(crbbeta180w * wgt) crbbeta180w, sum(idiovol * wgt) idiovol, sum(lnr05204w * wgt) lnr05204w,
sum(lnr18053w * wgt) lnr18053w, sum(mv_usd * wgt) mv_usd, sum(bp * wgt) bp
from factors f inner join totVal tv on f.sedolchk = tv.sedolchk
```

Comment: The problem is right there is your error message. "Procedure or function usp_cap_wgt_factors has too many arguments specified." It seems that your code has more parameters than the definition of the procedure. Perhaps if you shared the procedure code it would help.

Comment: I've added the sql procedure. I believe though it only had one parameter so don't really follow the error message

Comment: The error didn't specify whether input or output arguments were off. I don't know sql, but [looking at the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/runstoredprocedure.html#bujbg07-1) shows two oddities. Firstly, the examples don't contain an `as` keyword for the input variable (`@factDate as date`). Secondly, the examples with output parameters have the output defined at the beginning with the `OUTPUT` keyword. Are you sure your sql is correct?